# Ignore Duplicate Block in Python and Jinja2

Tags: python, yaml, jinja2

I need to avoid duplicate information from the output.I have a yaml config file as below.

```
**##CONFIG FILE**
vm_details: 
  vm1: 
    vm_flavour_name: small40
    vm_name: VM1
    vdu_connection_point: 
      CP1: 
        cp_name: OAM
        cp_net: NET1
        cp_interface_name: eth0
        cp_allowed_address_pairs: 10.69.15.0/24
      CP2: 
        cp_name: Tunnel
        cp_net: NET2
        cp_interface_name: eth1
        cp_allowed_address_pairs: 10.69.16.0/24
  vm2: 
    vm_flavour_name: small40
    vm_name: VM2
    vdu_connection_point: 
      CP1: 
        cp_name: OAM
        cp_net: NET1
        cp_interface_name: eth0
        cp_allowed_address_pairs: 10.69.15.0/24
      CP2: 
        cp_name: Tunnel
        cp_net: NET2
        cp_interface_name: eth1
        cp_allowed_address_pairs: 10.69.16.0/24
      CP3: 
        cp_name: EMX
        cp_net: NET3
        cp_interface_name: eth2
        cp_allowed_address_pairs: 10.69.17.0/24


**##Template File**

{% for vm_id, vm_info in vm_details.items()%}
    {% for cp_id,cp_info in vm_info.vm_connection_point.items() %}

<vm_details>
<id>{{ loop.index }}</id>
<cp_name>{{ cp_info['cp_name'] }}</cp_name>
<cp_net>{{ cp_info['cp_net_name'] }}</cp_net>
    <vm_depends_on>
{% set cp_name_vm_name = cp_info.cp_name %}
    {% for vm_id_alloc, vm_info_alloc in vm_details.items()%}
        {% for cp_id_alloc,cp_info_alloc in vm_info_alloc.vm_connection_point.items() %}
            {% if cp_info_alloc.cp_name == cp_name_vm_name %}
                    <vm>{{ vm_info_alloc['vm_name'] }}</vm>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </vm_depends_on>
</vm_details>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}


**##Python Code**

from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader, PackageLoader, select_autoescape

import yaml
import sys
import os
import os.path
import string
import platform
import uuid
import urllib2, base64, json
import ConfigParser, glob
import io
import shutil
import variable


sample_config = yaml.load(open('tosca_config.yml').read())
print sample_config

file_loader = FileSystemLoader('templates')
env = Environment(loader=file_loader,autoescape=True,trim_blocks=False,keep_trailing_newline=True)
template = env.get_template('vldd.txt')
autoescape = select_autoescape(['html', 'xml', 'Txt', 'txt', 'ml', 'ms', 'script.txt', 'Script.Txt']),

with open("templates/vld_temp.xml", "w") as fh:

    output_from_parsed_template=template.render(sample_config)

print(output_from_parsed_template)

with open("templates/vld_temp.xml", "w") as fh:
     fh.write(output_from_parsed_template)

with open('templates/vld_temp.xml') as infile, open('templates/vld.xml', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if not line.strip(): continue  # skip the empty line
        outfile.write(line)  # non-empty line. Write it to output

os.remove('templates/vld_temp.xml')
```

I am able to make for parse the data from config file using template and creating the xml file out of it. But problem is i am getting duplicate set as well.

Idea is to create vm_depends_on list for cp_name and cp_net.

```
**###Expected-Result:**
<vm_details>
<id>1</>
<cp_name>OAM</cp_name>
<cp_net>NET1</cp_net>
<vm_depends_on>
    <vm>VM1</vm>
    <vm>VM2</vm>
</vm_depends_on>
</vm_details>

<vm_details>
<id>2</>
<cp_name>Tunnel</cp_name>
<cp_net>NET2</cp_net>
<vm_depends_on>
    <vm>VM1</vm>
    <vm>VM2</vm>
</vm_depends_on>
</vm_details>

<vm_details>
<id>3</>
<cp_name>EMX</cp_name>
<cp_net>NET3</cp_net>
<vm_depends_on>
    <vm>VM2</vm>
</vm_depends_on>
</vm_details>

**###Current-Result:**

<vm_details>
    <id>1</id>
    <cp_name>OAM</cp_name>
    <cp_net>NET1</cp_net>
    <vm_depends_on>
        <vm>VM2</vm>
        <vm>VM1</vm>
    </vm_depends_on>
</vm_details>
<vm_details>
    <id>2</id>
    <cp_name>Tunnel</cp_name>
    <cp_net>NET2</cp_net>
    <vm_depends_on>
        <vm>VM2</vm>
        <vm>VM1</vm>
    </vm_depends_on>
</vm_details>
<vm_details>
    <id>3</id>
    <cp_name>EMX</cp_name>
    <cp_net>NET3</cp_net>
    <vm_depends_on>
        <vm>VM2</vm>
    </vm_depends_on>
</vm_details>
<vm_details>
    <id>1</id>
    <cp_name>OAM</cp_name>
    <cp_net>NET1</cp_net>
    <vm_depends_on>
        <vm>VM2</vm>
        <vm>VM1</vm>
    </vm_depends_on>
</vm_details>
<vm_details>
    <id>2</id>
    <cp_name>Tunnel</cp_name>
    <cp_net>NET2</cp_net>
    <vm_depends_on>
        <vm>VM2</vm>
        <vm>VM1</vm>
    </vm_depends_on>
</vm_details>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your input YML is quite similar to the expected output structure. You'd be better of just doing the few necessary data transformations in your application logic and then use a XML library, you could leverage a library such as [dicttoxml](https://pypi.org/project/dicttoxml/). Additionally I'd highly recommend you to use Python 3 instead of 2, [Python 2 end of life is in half a year](https://pythonclock.org).

### Python code

```py
import yaml
from dicttoxml import dicttoxml
# … other imports here

def transform_vm_config(config_data):  
   pass
   # Your data transformations here

# Transform input YML to output XML-format
sample_config = yaml.load(open('tosca_config.yml').read())
vm_data = transform_vm_config(sample_config)
vm_xml = dicttoxml(vm_data)

# Write to file
print(vm_xml)
```